# C++ Link Failure - ld: cannot find [makefile] [gcc/cygwin]

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, linker, cygwin

I am trying to create a system of makefiles to build my whole project. I am using cygwin and gcc compiler. I am running into a linking error on shared libraries that I cannot figure out.

I am concerned with `ld: cannot find -lbase` and `ld: cannot find -lsimsimA429`.
These files were clearly built. I even did a directory listing as part of the build command to show that they exist.

```
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 user group 116832 Mar 25 10:09 /cygdrive/d/myProj/lib/libbase.so
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 user group 75972  Mar 25 10:09 /cygdrive/d/myProj/lib/libsimsima429.so
```

and the link command also shows that I am including the correct link directory

```
g++  -shared  -L/cygdrive/d/myProj/lib -lpthread -lrt -lbase -lsimsimA429 ...
```

What am I doing wrong to incur this error?

Also, I am relatively new to writing makefiles. If you have any comments about how I could improve them, I would kindly appreciate a few comments.

*Full makefiles and output are listed below...*

---

**/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base/makefile**

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-- BASE
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#--
# Make does not offer a recursive wildcard function, so here's one:
rwildcard=$(wildcard $1$2) $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2))

MKDIR=mkdir

ROOTDIR=$(realpath ../../..)
PROJDIR=$(notdir $(CURDIR))
LIBDIR=$(ROOTDIR)/lib
OBJDIR=$(ROOTDIR)/obj/$(PROJDIR)
SRCDIR=$(ROOTDIR)/src

#OUTPUT FILE lib file or executable
TARGET=$(LIBDIR)/lib$(PROJDIR).so

INCLUDES=
#INCLUDES+=

LIBS=
#LIBS+=

LDFLAGS=
LDFLAGS+= -shared
LDFLAGS+= -L$(LIBDIR)
#LDFLAGS+= -Wl,-rpath


CCFLAGS=
#CCFLAGS+= -fPIC
#CCFLAGS+= -ansi
#CCFLAGS+= -pedantic
CCFLAGS+= -g
CCFLAGS+= -Wall
#CCFLAGS+= -std=c++11

CCC=g++
SRC= $(call rwildcard,./,*.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRC))

# Set our own Goal.
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    @$(MKDIR) -p $(abspath $(dir $@))
    $(CCC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CCC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
    ls -l $(TARGET)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)

test:
    @echo $(OBJECTS) | tr " " "\n"
```

**/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/simsimA429/makefile**

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-- SIMSIMA429
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#--
# Make does not offer a recursive wildcard function, so here's one:
rwildcard=$(wildcard $1$2) $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2))

MKDIR=mkdir

ROOTDIR=$(realpath ../../../../..)
PROJDIR=$(notdir $(CURDIR))
LIBDIR=$(ROOTDIR)/lib
OBJDIR=$(ROOTDIR)/obj/$(PROJDIR)
SRCDIR=$(ROOTDIR)/src

#OUTPUT FILE lib file or executable
TARGET=$(LIBDIR)/lib$(PROJDIR).so

INCLUDES=
INCLUDES+= -I$(SRCDIR)/face
INCLUDES+= -I$(SRCDIR)/sfi/base
INCLUDES+= -I$(SRCDIR)/sfi/drivers/a429/include

LIBS=
LIBS+= -L$(LIBDIR)
#LIBS+= -lbase

LDFLAGS=
LDFLAGS+= -shared
#LDFLAGS+= -Wl,-rpath


CCFLAGS=
#CCFLAGS+= -fPIC
#CCFLAGS+= -ansi
#CCFLAGS+= -pedantic
CCFLAGS+= -g
CCFLAGS+= -Wall
#CCFLAGS+= -std=c++11

CCC=g++
SRC= $(call rwildcard,./,*.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRC))

# Set our own Goal.
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    @$(MKDIR) -p $(abspath $(dir $@))
    $(CCC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CCC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
    ls -l $(TARGET)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)

test:
    @echo $(OBJECTS) | tr " " "\n"
```

**/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/ioss/makefile**

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-- IOSS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#--
# Make does not offer a recursive wildcard function, so here's one:
rwildcard=$(wildcard $1$2) $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2))

MKDIR=mkdir

ROOTDIR=$(realpath ../../..)
PROJDIR=$(notdir $(CURDIR))
LIBDIR=$(ROOTDIR)/lib
OBJDIR=$(ROOTDIR)/obj/$(PROJDIR)
SRCDIR=$(ROOTDIR)/src

#OUTPUT FILE lib file or executable
TARGET=$(LIBDIR)/lib$(PROJDIR).so

INCLUDES=
INCLUDES+= -I$(SRCDIR)/face
INCLUDES+= -I$(SRCDIR)/sfi
INCLUDES+= -I$(SRCDIR)/sfi/base
INCLUDES+= -I$(SRCDIR)/sfi/drivers/a429/include
INCLUDES+= -I$(SRCDIR)/sfi/ioss

LIBS=
LIBS+= -L$(LIBDIR)
LIBS+= -lpthread
LIBS+= -lrt
LIBS+= -lbase
LIBS+= -lsimsima429

LDFLAGS=
LDFLAGS+= -shared
#LDFLAGS+= -Wl,-rpath


CCFLAGS=
#CCFLAGS+= -fPIC
#CCFLAGS+= -ansi
#CCFLAGS+= -pedantic
CCFLAGS+= -g
CCFLAGS+= -Wall
#CCFLAGS+= -std=c++11

CCC=g++
SRC= $(call rwildcard,./,*.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRC))

# Set our own Goal.
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    @$(MKDIR) -p $(abspath $(dir $@))
    $(CCC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CCC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) 
    ls -l $(TARGET)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)

test:
    @echo $(OBJECTS) | tr " " "\n"
```

**Full Output:**

```
10:09:19 **** Build of configuration Default for project base ****
make -j all 
g++ -c  -g -Wall  udpserver.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/base/./udpserver.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  udpclient.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/base/./udpclient.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  impl/clock.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/base/./impl/clock.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  impl/deque.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/base/./impl/deque.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  impl/thread.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/base/./impl/thread.o
g++  -shared -L/cygdrive/d/myProj/lib  -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/lib/libbase.so /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/base/./udpserver.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/base/./udpclient.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/base/./impl/clock.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/base/./impl/Stdafx.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/base/./impl/deque.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/base/./impl/thread.o
ls -l /cygdrive/d/myProj/lib/libbase.so
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 user group 116832 Mar 25 10:09 /cygdrive/d/myProj/lib/libbase.so

10:09:25 Build Finished (took 5s.994ms)

10:09:25 **** Build of configuration Default for project simsimA429 ****
make all 
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include A429HwCtrlTx.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/simsima429/./A429HwCtrlTx.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include A429HwCtrlRx.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/simsima429/./A429HwCtrlRx.o
g++  -shared  -L/cygdrive/d/myProj/lib -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/lib/libsimsima429.so /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/simsima429/./A429HwCtrlTx.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/simsima429/./A429HwCtrlRx.o
ls -l /cygdrive/d/myProj/lib/libsimsima429.so
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 user group 75972 Mar 25 10:09 /cygdrive/d/myProj/lib/libsimsima429.so

10:09:29 Build Finished (took 4s.339ms)

10:09:29 **** Build of configuration Default for project ioss ****
make -j all 
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/ioss IOS.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./IOS.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/ioss message/IOSmsg.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./message/IOSmsg.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/ioss message/MsgId.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./message/MsgId.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/ioss message/IOSmsgA429.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./message/IOSmsgA429.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/ioss interface/IOSInterfaceHandle.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./interface/IOSInterfaceHandle.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/ioss interface/IOSInterface.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./interface/IOSInterface.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/ioss interface/direct/IOSDirect_Interface.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./interface/direct/IOSDirect_Interface.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/ioss bus/a429/A429MajorFrame.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./bus/a429/A429MajorFrame.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/ioss bus/a429/A429MsgRxControl.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./bus/a429/A429MsgRxControl.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/ioss bus/a429/A429BusTx.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./bus/a429/A429BusTx.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/ioss bus/a429/A429MsgRegistry.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./bus/a429/A429MsgRegistry.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/ioss bus/a429/A429BusRx.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./bus/a429/A429BusRx.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/ioss bus/a429/A429Message.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./bus/a429/A429Message.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/ioss bus/a429/A429MsgBuffer.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./bus/a429/A429MsgBuffer.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/ioss bus/m1553/M1553Connection.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./bus/m1553/M1553Connection.o
g++ -c  -g -Wall  -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/face -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/base -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/drivers/a429/include -I/cygdrive/d/myProj/src/sfi/ioss config/IOSConfig.cpp -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./config/IOSConfig.o
g++  -shared  -L/cygdrive/d/myProj/lib -lpthread -lrt -lbase -lsimsima429 -o /cygdrive/d/myProj/lib/libioss.so /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./IOS.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./message/IOSmsg.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./message/MsgId.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./message/IOSmsgA429.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./interface/IOSInterfaceHandle.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./interface/IOSInterface.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./interface/direct/IOSDirect_Interface.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./bus/a429/A429MajorFrame.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./bus/a429/A429MsgRxControl.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./bus/a429/A429BusTx.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./bus/a429/A429MsgRegistry.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./bus/a429/A429BusRx.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./bus/a429/A429Message.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./bus/a429/A429MsgBuffer.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./bus/m1553/M1553Connection.o /cygdrive/d/myProj/obj/ioss/./config/IOSConfig.o 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lbase
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lsimsima429
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:61: recipe for target '/cygdrive/d/myProj/lib/libioss.so' failed
make: *** [/cygdrive/d/myProj/lib/libioss.so] Error 1

10:09:42 Build Finished (took 13s.205ms)
```

Comment: `simsima429` is not the same as `simsimA429` (assuming cygwin doesn't case-fold the way Windows does) but that doesn't explain the `base` issue.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the case and I am getting the same error with the new case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin shared libraries are `*.dll` files, not `lib*.so` files. I suppose your linker is struggling to find `base.dll` and `simsimA429.dll`.